# Can I lock a post in position, so it always appears on the homepage?

Tags: posts

I'm a complete noob when it comes to Wordpress, but I've joined a company who use it as their website and they need an answer quickly.
I want to know if I can I lock a post in position, so it always appears on the homepage ? I don't want to use a plug-in (preferably) 
Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [Sticky Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the theme you are using.  You might want to look into creating a page for your home page and then going into settings > reading and making that page your static home page.  If you want to lock a single post on your front page and your theme lets you... try :

I the Post editor find the "Publish" section.  Next to "Visibility" click on edit and then check the "Stick this post to the front page" option there.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has such functionality natively and it is called [Sticky Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts).

In post editor `Publish` metabox click `Edit` next to `Visibility`, check `Stick this post to the front page` and save post.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your replies.
Rarst... Although your post was a little clearer for me to understand, I've marked Scott's answer as the accepted one as he needs more points - you've got thousands !!!!
But thank you very, very much :)